# Update one SQL value in a table after changing a value from another table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I have a table categories with the following columns:
Id, Category, Vat, Tax

And a products tables with the following columns:
Id, idCategory, Code, Product, Stock, buyingPrice, sellingPrice, Sales

When creating a new product the value of a product is entered and the buyingPrice is calculated by adding the Vat and Tax from the categories table to the value.

The sellingPrice is then calculated by a percentage markup of the buying price.

I now want to be able to automatically update the buyingPrice of all products if the Vat or Tax is changed.

I have tried creating a trigger but I am currently unable to work it out. I'm not sure if it's because the original value is not saved or if I am doing it all wrong. I have never created a trigger before so any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Pleas publish your trigger attempt. BTW there isn't a value in your product table?

Comment: Maybe don't store the buyingprice!?!?

Comment: Yes, please show us what you have so far. What happens with the trigger that you're running, is it giving any response or feedback? Does any data get inserted or does the entire insert fail?

Answer (score 0):

I think Strawberry has a great comment here; you should store the VAT and tax separately and apply them to the base price that you store, rather than storing it as a final selling price that includes VAT or tax.

In your scenario, what happens if the VAT is reduced by 0.5%? Your trigger can be modified to properly account for newly inserted items, but how will you go back and correct existing ones? In the US, an item can be exempt from sales tax (if the purchaser is a certain type of non-profit organization or other exempt business, or in certain states during a sales-tax holiday). Again, in the US, sales tax calculations regarding putting an item on sale can be complicated. I'm not making the assumption that your situation will require dealing with those situations, but it seems like it would benefit you to not need to recalculate every item in your database if any of these were to apply.

If you really insist on this, I'd personally rather use a view to calculate the price on the fly rather than using a trigger to calculate it on insertion, but that's just me. Again, I'd ultimately prefer to handle this in the application logic.